# Tic Tac Toe logic

Tags: php, math

Imagine that squares in a TicTacToe grid are numbered in a linear fashion from 1 to 9. A player puts an X on the grid by calling a class method:

`$game->putX(1, 1);` (the method accepts only integers from 0 to 2).

How do I calculate the linear value of the field where X was placed (here the linear value is 5)?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the first `1` meaning `X`, and the second `1` meaning the grid number? Or the other way around? Or am I completely off?

Comment: The integers passed to the method are coordinates. The first '1' is X coordinate and the second '1' is and Y coordinate on the TicTacToe grid.

Comment: I don't understand. How are you going to put an X on, say (5,5) if the method only accepts integers from 0-2 ?

Comment: In the coordinates system a TicTacToe grid wouldn't accept a coordinate greater than 2 (you start counting from 0 and you have three rows and three columns in the grid). The question is about converting coordinates system into linear system where each square is numbered in a linear fashion (there are 9 squares in total in the grid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually just `x*3 + y+1`. Assuming the games state is saved in an array (indexed 1-9, according to your question), your code could look like this:

```
// the board:      examples:
//   x 0 1 2       0 0 -> 1
// y               1 1 -> 5
// 0   1 2 3       2 2 -> 9
// 1   4 5 6
// 2   7 8 9

putX ($x, $y) {
  $this->state[$x*3+$y+1] = 'X';
}
```